# What does the "^=" operator do in this find non-paired number algorithm?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Saw an interesting piece of code to find a lonely number in a list of duplicate numbers (where every number in the list occurs twice except for one).

```js
function findNonPaired(listOfNumbers) {
  let nonPairedNumber = 0

  listOfNumbers.forEach((n) => {
      nonPairedNumber ^= n
  })

  return nonPairedNumber
}

const x = [1,5,4,3,9,2,3,1,4,5,9]
console.log(findNonPaired(x))
```

This solution looks very elegant, but I'm curious at to what the `^=` operator is actually doing here?

Comment: @CumuloNimbus Those are carrots (different word). Just to note, `^=` also has a meaning in CSS, to [match the beginning of an attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). The meaning is similar to the ["start of string" anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) from regular expressions. You can apply CSS's `^=` to JavaScript by using `document.querySelectorAll('[name^=form1-]')` which finds all elements with a "name" attribute that begins with "form1-"

Comment: As a side note, this function can be a one-liner: `findUnique = list => list.reduce((out, n) => out ^ n, 0)`

Comment: @CumuloNimbus _Carets_. Carrots are the things in the ground that Bugs Bunny likes.

Comment: Have you considered consulting a reference manual? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_assignment.asp

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`a ^= b` is the same as `a = a ^ b` where `^` is the bitwise XOR operator.

```
0 ^ 0 === 0
1 ^ 0 === 1
0 ^ 1 === 1
1 ^ 1 === 0
```

This is a neat algorithm. Let's trace one execution with the list `[8, 12, 8]` for example:

```
0 ^ 8 = 0000 ^ 1000 = 1000
        1000 ^ 1100 = 0100
        0100 ^ 1000 = 1100 = 12
```

The word "duplicate" isn't correct. This algorithm tests for *parity*. A simple but somewhat wrong definition is "when everything has a *pair*". pair...parity.

`[2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5,5]` will return `2` because everything else has a pair.

`[3,4,5]` will actually return 2 (`011^100^101` -> `010`) because that is the xor of all the unpaired items.

Comment: Cool stuff, thanks for the explanation and examples

Comment: Therefore, the algorithm isn't "neat" at all, because it pretends to find "unique number", while in your example [2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5,5] it falsely finds 2 despite 2 being part of a triplet, and therefore not unique, and in your [3,4,5] finding 2, which isn't even in the list, and failing to find the three unique numbers that are actually there. This is one of those things a programmer can "get away with" until those conditions no longer apply, at which point it fails spectacularly, as your last example demonstrates.

Comment: @MontyHarder Usually people make an argument before saying "Therefore"... Also thanks for your opinion on this algorithm's neatness. However, it correctly finds 2 in this example b/c it is the only unpaired number. Admittedly "unique" was a bad word choice by me, and "non-paired" would be a better choice of words, as pointed out by JoeFrambach

Comment: @MontyHarder You could say the same thing about any algorithm if you fail to satisfy its preconditions. The question was quite clear that it operates on a list of numbers where each number appears twice except for one. While you have certainly shown that it doesn't work outside of that, that's a strawman argument; no one was claiming that it would.

Comment: @MontyHarder Did I say something wrong in my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Like other answers say - it is a bitwise XOR.

About the algorythm - it is cool if you are sure that the duplicates are even count. When a number is XOR-ed with `x` and later again XOR-ed with `x` it will return to it's previuos value. If one number is seen 3 times in this chain, the 3-rd occurence will fool this algorythm.
Also if there is one more value that is single in the chain, like:

```
a, b, c, X, a, c, b, Y
```

the result will be `(X ^ Y)` and you can't be sure if you have one unique value or more.

Comment: No sane person wants to inherit responsibility for code like this, which doesn't document the assumptions (and we know what happens when we ASS|U|ME) it makes.